# KStream incompatible types

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I was trying something  with coding part by using strings and came up with the code below , please help with the syntax issues with the code.

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> textlines = builder.stream("INTOPIC");
KStream<String, String> mstream = textlines
    .foreach(new ForeachAction<String, String>(){
        public void apply(String key, String value){
            String str=value.replace("[","");
            for(int y=0; y<str.length(); y++){
                //System.out.print(str.charAt(y));
            }
            //System.out.print("\n");
        }
    });
mstream.to("OUTTOPIC");
```

In the second KStream statement it is showing incompatible types.....
I want the replace logic to work with and it should be affected to textlines variable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `foreach` is the `void`, not the next `KStream`. If you want to transform data, then you need to use `map` instead...

Code will look following way (especially if you need to change key as well, if not - see next variant):

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
KStream<String, String> textlines = builder.stream("INTOPIC");
KStream<String, String> mstream = textlines
    .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(key, value.replace("[",""))));
mstream.to("OUTTOPIC");
```

or you can replace lines 3-4 with following (it will result in better execution):

```
KStream<String, String> mstream = textlines
    .mapValues(value -> value.replace("[",""));
```

Comment: Can u just send me the edited code for above..i didnt understand properly

Comment: I've added the code to show it, but I recommend before jumping into coding to read documentation (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html) - the Kafka Streams conceptually is simple, but it's better to grok the basics first

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked for me...and one more question is how can i remove null which is displaying as the key  in "KStream<key, value>"

Comment: Kafka messages always have a key that you can simply ignore if its not needed

Comment: I meant "logically ignore" - to output data to Kafka you need to have key, if you don't specify it - then it's specirfied as NULL

Comment: Yea but that null is getting displayed which sholud not happen...how to avoid null getting displayed?

Comment: How do you display data? console-consumer or something else?

Comment: I don't remember that it's possible out of the box... But I maybe forgotten

Comment: Just a follow up: it's always better to use `mapValues()` if you don't care about the key -- it will most likely give you better execution.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax completely agree - i did use plain map just to show direct mapping between input and output

Comment: Mind updating your answer to point this out? Not sure if people read comments :)

Comment: In kafka console consumer command, just making key.print = false will display only value...

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Just removing --property print.key=true this on my kafka-cosole-consumer command works for not displaying null on console....but the thing is it is not just for the display purpose i am using....my outputs from kafka streams need to go directly to the stream reactor, stream reactor cannot accept null and then value..so what can be the solution for this?

Comment: Just add a `.filter()` before `to()` and filter out records with `null`.